# How do I solve this inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve this equation? $7(-7b-2)<231$
I do not know where the $231$ should move to.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Simply expand:

-49b - 14 < 231

(add 14 to both sides)

-49b < 231 + 14 = 245

(divide both sides by 49)

-b < 5

b > -5

(Remember to flip the inequality sign when dividing by negatives)

Comment: Any reason for the anonymous down votes?

Answer (score 2):

$$ 7(-7b-2)<231$$
$$-7b-2 < 33$$
$$-7b < 35$$
$$b > -5$$

The relative sign changes to the opposite, when multiplying or divinding with a negative number.